# My older simple code to coalesce two data frames in R is no longer working despite not changing

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce

I'm back to back to an older R script I wrote a year ago where I was coalescing two data frames with the same column names. I was using simple code: `temp_2_1 <- dplyr::coalesce(tp2, tp1)`

`tp2` and `tp1` are both data frames that have 4 columns with the same name. Before, the code would look in `tp2` and if there was a NA value it would look in `tp1` and pull the value from it into the place the NA was in `tp2` for each of the four columns. The new data frame would stored in `temp_2_1`.

Now nothing is coalesced and `temp_2_1` is simply a copy of `tp2`. My code did not change. My R version is `R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)` and my dplyr version is `dplyr_1.1.1`. I was likely using an older version of both before, but can't find any documentation of a change that may have occured.

I've tried it without `dplyr::`, I've it column by column and nothing works.

I expect it to coalesce.

Comment: Thanks I see that documentation now. The update invalidates how I was using it before. 

Is there an alternative to brining in data rowwise from other data frames to replace NAs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr::coalesce` used to do column-by-column coalescing between two data.frames. Since v1.1.0 it follows the definition of missingness from `vctrs`, which considers only rows that are completely missing.

So for example, consider these two data.frames:

```
ex1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, 2, NA), v2 = c(1, NA, NA))
ex2 <- data.frame(v1 = 4:6, v2 = 4:6)
```

For `ex1`, we have some missingness in row 2, and row 3 is completely missing. Using `coalesce`:

```
coalesce(ex1, ex2)
```

> ```
>   v1 v2
> 1  1  1
> 2  2 NA
> 3  6  6
> ```

We see that only row 3 gets replaced with the values from `ex2`.

To get the old behaviour, you can call `coalesce` on each column yourself. E.g. here is an easy `purrr` solution:

```
map2_dfc(ex1, ex2, coalesce)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 × 2
>      v1    v2
>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1     1
> 2     2     5
> 3     6     6
> ```